# What are these worms in my peaches?

Tags: insects

it’s February in Melbourne Australia and I have a peach tree full of peaches which themselves are full of these worms (pictured below), I’ve lasted them out on a leaf for contrast purposes but they were found within the peach. Does anyone know what they are?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

That is a "**maggot**" infestation. It is the **larva of a fly**. The exact species of fly is not known. I am attaching a couple of links that describe "**Queensland fruit fly**", an Australian species which may be the culprit. If it is not (Queensland is quite distant from you), you should check for further information more locally to you.

http://agriculture.vic.gov.au/agriculture/pests-diseases-and-weeds/pest-insects-and-mites/queensland-fruit-fly/gardeners

http://agriculture.vic.gov.au/agriculture/pests-diseases-and-weeds/pest-insects-and-mites/queensland-fruit-fly/appearance-and-life-cycle